# On Cohomology of stable sheaves on $\mathbb P^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F$ be a stable torsion free sheaf (not necessarily a bundle) on $\mathbb P^2$. Is it necessarily true that $Ext^2(F,F) \cong \text{Hom}(F, F(-3))^*$?

My guess is that one needs to proceed as follows : $Ext^2(F,F) \cong H^2(\mathbb P^2, \mathcal{E}nd(F)) \cong H^0(\mathbb P^2, \mathcal{E}nd(F)(-3)))^* \cong H^0(\mathbb P^2, \mathcal{H}om (F, F(-3)))^* \cong \text{Hom}(F, F(-3))^* $

Here, I have some doubts about this strategy:

$(i)$ Is the first identification correct for stable sheaves (instead of a bundle). Can someone give the precise identification in this case?

$(ii)$ For the second identification, we are using Serre duality and for that we need $\mathcal{E}nd(F)$ to be a bundle. Is this always the case?

$(iii)$ Assuming the first two identifications to be true and third and fourth identifications follow from definition, can we say that $\text{Hom}(F, F(-3)) \cong H^0(\mathbb P^2, F(-3))^*$?

$(iv)$ If the answer to the previous question is not necessarily true and if we know that the slope of $F$ is bigger that slope of $F(-3)$, then can we conclude $\text{Hom}(F, F(-3))=0$?

$(v)$ Can we avoid using $\mathcal{E}nd(F)$ and still obtain $Ext^2(F,F) \cong \text{Hom}(F, F(-3))^*$?

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Serre duality holds for all coherent sheaves, you even don't need to assume that there is no torsion.

Comment: @Sasha, I now think that the first identification is from definition $Ext^2(F,F)=R^2(\text{Hom}(F,F))=R^2(\Gamma(\mathcal{H}om(F,F)))=H^2(\mathbb P^2, \mathcal{H}om(F,F))=Hom(\mathcal{H}om(F,F), \mathcal O(-3))^*$.. where $R^2$ is the second right derived functor and $\Gamma$ is the global section functor(please correct me if this is wrong).but is it obvious to see that the last expression is precisely $Hom(F, F(-3))^*$?

Comment: Serre duality gives the required isomorphism immediately, no intermediate step is required.

Comment: @Sasha, I'm confused, may be I'm missing something obvious. Could you please give a hint why by Serre duality its immediate that $H^2(\mathbb P^2, \mathcal{E}nd(F))=\text{Hom}(F, F(-3))^*$. I just realised that both my explainations in the question and in the comment to reach $\text{Hom}(F, F(-3))^*$ are not quite correct. I guess we are not allowed to use $H^i(X, E)=H^{n-i}(X, E^*\otimes K)^*$ as then we have to make sense of $\mathcal{E}nd(F))^*$. On the other hand, if we use $Ext^i(E,K) =H^{n-i}(X, E)^*$ with $E=\mathcal{E}nd(F))$, then it is not clear to me how to get to $Hom(F, F(-3))^*$.

Comment: Serre duality gives an isomorphism $$\mathrm{Ext}^i(F_1,F_2) \cong \mathrm{Ext}^{n-i}(F_2,F_1 \otimes \omega_X)^\vee$$ for any coherent sheaves (and even for any objects of the derived category) on any smooth projective variety $X$ of dimension $n$. There is no need to "reach" anything via cohomology.

Comment: @Sasha, Thank you very much for this general result. Could please give me a reference (or is this in Hartshorne? where in Hartshorne?)

Comment: See, e.g., Theorem 3.12 in Huybrechts, D. Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry. Oxford Mathematical Monographs. The Clarendon Press, Oxford University Press, Oxford, 2006. viii+307 pp.

Comment: @Sasha, Thanks.